# How to scrape content from div class using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a part of the html page i want to scrape

[image]

I am trying to get the title and the value of cryptos using beautifulsoup.

I have tried many solutions using find and find_all to get the content included in div but I don't see what is wrong... There is an example of what i tried:

```
titles = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "tabTitle-qQlkPW5Y"})
```

Can you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use selenium to make sure the page fully rendered. Then using beautiful soup we can navigate through its elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(pathToChromeWebDriver)
url = "https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/global-charts/"
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for title in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "tabTitle-qQlkPW5Y"}):
     print(title.string)
```

Comment: The problem is that the array/list is empty

Comment: can you provide the website url you want to scrape

Comment: here it is : https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/global-charts/

Comment: it seems that your scrapped HTML page is not fully loaded. I already modify my solution above and it's works